# Proof: product of segments of a triangle's base are equal, given conditions on the angles involved

Tags: geometry

> In a triangle $ABC$, the angle $C$ is obtuse and the point $D$ is the foot of the altitude from the vertex $C$. The points $P$ and $Q$ are on the segment $\overline{AB}$ and $\angle PCB = \angle ACQ = 90^\circ$. Prove that $|AP|\cdot |DQ| = |PD|\cdot |QB|$.

[image: a hand-drawn sketch of the triangle, segments and angles involved]

I have tried with law of sine and similarity of triangle. And found:

$QB \cdot PC \cdot \sin B = QC \cdot AP \cdot \sin A,$ then

$$PC = \frac{PD}{\sin \angle PCD},  QC =  \frac{DQ}{\sin \angle QCD},$$

So, $AP \cdot DQ \cdot \sin (\angle PCD) \cdot \sin A = PD \cdot QB \cdot \sin (\angle QCD) \cdot \sin B$

Now $\angle PCD = 90-A-x$ and $\angle QCD = 90-B-x$

where $ x = \angle ACP = \angle QCB$ but could not prove after that. What can be used to finish the proof?

Comment: I noticed you used mathjax only to write your question and not for your working. Your question may not be well received if you do not use mathjax so please learn and use. I edited this time.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to learn mathjax and how much time will it require?

Comment: Please use the below link for basic tutorial. It should not take much time for basic things like how to write fraction, angle etc. You can refer to the link when typing questions and after a few times, you would anyway remember it. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

As $CP$ is tangent to circumcircle of $\triangle BCD$, using power of a point,

$CP^2 = CD^2 + PD^2 = PD \cdot PB = PD \cdot (PD + DQ + QB)$

$CD^2 = PD \cdot (DQ + QB) \tag1$

Also $CQ$ is tangent to circumcircle of $\triangle ADC$,

$CQ^2 = CD^2 + QD^2 = QD \cdot QA = QD \cdot (QD + DP + PA) $

$CD^2 = QD \cdot (DP + PA) \tag2$

Now equate $(1)$ and $(2)$ to finish.

Answer (score 2):

You said you got

$$AP\cdot DQ\cdot \sin \angle PCD \sin \angle A = PD\cdot QB\cdot \sin\angle QCD \sin \angle B$$

But from similar triangles $\triangle PCD \sim \triangle PBC$,

$$\sin\angle PCD = \sin \angle B$$

And from similar triangles $\triangle QCD \sim \triangle QAC$,

$$\sin\angle QCD = \sin \angle A$$

As long as $\angle A \ne 0$ and $\angle B \ne 0$, the sines can be cancelled on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

From similar triangles $\triangle PCD \sim \triangle CBD$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{PD}{CD} &= \frac{CD}{DB}\\
PD\cdot DB &= CD^2 \tag1
\end{align*}$$

And from similar triangles $\triangle QCD \sim \triangle CAD$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{DQ}{CD} &= \frac{CD}{AD}\\
AD\cdot DQ &= CD^2 \tag2
\end{align*}$$

Then equating two forms of $CD^2$:

$$\begin{align*}
AD\cdot DQ &= PD\cdot DB\\
AD\cdot DQ - PD\cdot DQ &= PD\cdot DB - PD\cdot DQ\\
(AD-PD)\cdot DQ &= PD\cdot(DB-PD)\\
AP\cdot DQ&= PD\cdot QB
\end{align*}$$